# Django Tutorial: .choice_set.all not being called

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am new to the Django Framework and can't seem to identify why my detail.html is not rendering properly. It appears as though my forloop that iterates over choice in question.choice_set.all is not being hit. If someone could help identify why it would be very helpful.

detail.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{%     endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
<label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}    

</label><br />

<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}"
value="{{ choice.id }}" />
{% endfor %}


<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

Views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from .models import Choice, Question

# Long Method of return HttpResponse
# def index(request):
#     latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
#     template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
#     context = {
#         'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
#     }

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
    # render takes the request (object,template,dictionary<optional>)


# def detail(request, question_id):
#     try:
#         question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
#     except Question.DoesNotExist:
#         raise Http404("Question does not exist")
#     return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

# SHORTCUT TO USE GET AND RASIE 404
def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})




def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

urls.py

```
# map views to url
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'

urlpatterns = [
    #ex: polls/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    #ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),

    #ex: /polls/5//results/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),

    #ex: /polls/5/vote
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

** Here is my data model**
model.py

```
# Pythons Imports for built in modules
import datetime



from django.db import models

from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    #string method for question object representation
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)



class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

 # Running  python manage.py makemigrations polls instructs django of
 # changes to your model
```

Comment: Question model please?

Comment: I have added my model, also by error I am referring to my output continuing to fall through to "you didn't select a choice" in my Forloop.

Comment: My answer below is not correct. the choice_set is perfectly valid in the template. The work around is also fine. I'm not sure what exactly caused the problem now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a work around, you can add a function to your `question` model that grabs all relative information and generates a dictionary. Pass the dictionary through and you can access the information through the template.

This is a small example in my project

models.py under the student class

```
def get_homework(self):
    '''get all homeworks of classes related to this student'''
    dict = {}
    dict['notification'] = False
    dict['content'] = {}
    for my_class in self.related_class.all():
        homework_list = []
        for class_homework in my_class.related_homework.filter(due_date__gte=date.today()):
            if class_homework.due_date == date.today():
                dict['notification'] = True
            homework = {}
            homework['name_chinese'] = class_homework.name_chinese
            homework['assigned_by'] = class_homework.assigned_by
            homework['homework_content'] = class_homework.homework_content
            homework['assign_date'] = class_homework.assign_date
            homework['due_date'] = class_homework.due_date
            homework['submission'] = class_homework.submission
            homework_list.append(homework)
        dict['content'][my_class.name_chinese] = homework_list
    return dict
```

views.py

```
dict = student.get_homework()
return render(request,'ParentHomework.html',dict)
```

Comment: Sorry, this is just flat out wrong. That code is perfectly valid in a template.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you were right. I tried myself and its working fine. Should I delete? It just seems not intuitive for me to do query in the template logic.

Answer (score 1):

Register "Choice" in "polls/admin.py"

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Question
from .models import Choice

admin.site.register(Question)
admin.site.register(Choice)
```

After that add some choices in your admin panel and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Here we have created two models i.e. "Question" & "Choice".

By following the tutorial we have added data in Question model by using our Admin privilege.
But we have not added anything in "Choice" table that's why **"question.choice_set.all"** is returning nothing(null) and because of that the **"{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}"**
is not executing.

I have just added a line of code for demo in details.html

```
{{ question.question_text }}

{{ question.choice_set.all }}

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{%endif %}
```

[image]

Here as we can see QuerySet is empty.

I have manually entered data in "Choice" table after that when I am executing my code I am getting radio button and label in output which was expected and it shows that for loop is working.
[image]

While entering data in Choice table just keep in mind that question_id is foreign key in choice table. So its value should match any one value of id from question table.

There might be other better solution, but this is what I have figured out. I am also a newbie trying to learn django.

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

```
choice_set.all

relatedclasslowercasename_set.all
```

Reference:

https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/22poxo/basic_django_tutorial_question_about_pchoice/