# Error while implementing django tutorial - QuerySet is empty

Tags: python, django

Can someone explain how to manually enter data in "Choice" table?
I am following the django tutorial and my QuerySet is empty like yugal sinha has mentioned here:
[A solution without an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404653/django-tutorial-choice-set-all-not-being-called/67658250#67658250)
How can I fix this issue?

**Picture of the problem:**
What I am getting (QuerySet is empty):
[image]
What I had to get:
[image]

**EDIT 1:**

In my opinion something has to be changed in the `class Choice` in the `models.py`

I will add my code

- which is due to the django tutorial:
  [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial04/)

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Question
from .models import Choice
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Choice, Question




def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))

# Create your views here.
```

**polls\urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

**0001_initial.py**

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Question',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('question_text', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('pub_date', models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date published')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Choice',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('choice_text', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('votes', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('question', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='polls.question')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

# Create your models here.
```

**results.html**

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

**detail.html**

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{{ question.choice_set.all }}
<!--{{ question.choice_set.all }}-->


{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

**index.html**

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>


    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: can you please give more information about the problem your facing. Like the part of code that is not working or something like that.

Comment: I've attached my code and also the source to the tutorial.  
In my opinion the problem is at ```models.py``` while declaring the ```class Choice```.

Comment: You didn't provided views.py, please check, its the data from the migrations file.

Comment: You are right - I'm sorry.  I have updated it now with the ```views.py``` file.

Comment: I've added the relevant data, someone is manage to find a solution?